# Calculate the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty } \sqrt[n]{4^{n}-3^{n-2}} $

Tags: limits

I am trying to calculate the limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{4^{n}-3^{n-2}}$$ My progression so far is rewiring as:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(4^{n}-3^{n}\cdot\frac{1}{9}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Are my steps correct? How do I continue?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Rewrite as $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{4^n - 3^{n-2}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} 4 \sqrt[n] {1 - \frac{1}{9} \left( \frac{3}{4}\right)^n}$$ and consider the limiting behavior of the term under the radical sign.

Comment: so the answer is 4?

Comment: Yes, it is. If $f(n) \to 1$, then $\sqrt[n]{f(n)} \to 1$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\sqrt[n]{4^{n}-3^{n-2}}\sim  \sqrt[n]{4^{n}}$$

Comment: so the answer is 4?

Comment: Yes of course indeed $4^n>>3^{n-2}$ that is $$\frac{4^n-3^{n-2}}{4^n}\to 1$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also evaluate the limit in the following way

$$\begin{aligned}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{4^n-3^{n-2}} &= \lim_{n\to\infty}4\left({1-\frac{1}{9}\left( \frac{3}{4}\right)^n}\right)^\frac1n=4\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1{9\left(\frac43\right)^n}\right)^\frac1n=\\
&=4\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1{9\left(\frac43\right)^n}\right)^{9\left(\frac43\right)^n\frac19\left(\frac34\right)^n\frac1n}=\\
&=4\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1{9\left(\frac43\right)^n}\right)^{9\left(\frac43\right)^n}\right)^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac19\left(\frac34\right)^n\frac1n}=\\
&=4\left(e^{-1}\right)^0=4
\end{aligned}$$